# can't set the property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `SourceViewController` and a `DesViewController` , there's a variable in `DesViewController` :  `@property ( nonatomic , assign , readwrite ) NSString* name ;`

but here's a problem when I call the method in SourceViewController :

```
-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil ] ;
    DestinationViewController* desViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController ] ;
    desViewController.name = @"haah" ;
    [self presentViewController:desViewController animated:YES completion:nil ] ;
}
```

the output :

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SourceViewController setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a0d7c0'
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are you sure the initial view controller is set as a `DesViewController` and not a `SourceViewController`?

Comment: maybe it's not , how can i solve this  probelm

Comment: Are you in the App Delegate? Often there are problems if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is right now, the viewcontroller you instantiate doesnt seem to be of class DestinationViewcontroller (since your initial viewController doesn't seem to be of that class). So it doesnt have that property. You have to instantiate the correct class (see below). 
Also check if you synthesized the property in implementation of DestinationViewcontroller.

And on a side note: though you may want to simply assign the string variable to a new value, most of the times you'd want to use copy instead of assign on NStrings.  Also, the readwrite is not necessary since its the default behaviour.
So, better change your property declaration thusly:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

And in implementation check if you synthesize for example like this:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
```

And in your dealloc:

```
[_name release];
```

Also, consider using ARC if you stat a new project.

Now, if you make your viewController a DestinationViewcontroller, it should work.
Best way to get is would be

```
DestinationViewcontroller *dc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier of your desviewcontroller"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The below line of code:

```
[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController ] ;
```

It returns SourceViewController. This is because, it is set as your initial viewController.
However, you are treating it as a  `DestinationViewController`. Hence the problem.

Either change your initial controller or declare and synthesize property for `SourceViewController`.

Comment: Yes, better to check what [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController ] is returning. You can easily do it by accepting the object into an id and then type cast accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising property on `SourceViewController` while trying to accede from `DestinationViewController`.

You need to create property for `DestinationViewController`.